# The size of arrow in an equation is not suitable

Tags: arrows

I have a mathematical note as follows;

```
$$\left.\begin{array}{rl}
x\notin f(C)\overset{C\cap f^{-1}(D)\subseteq C}{\longrightarrow} & x\notin f\big(C\cap f^{-1}(D)\big)\\
& x\in U
\end{array}\right\}\Longrightarrow x\in V$$
```

But as you are seeing the arrow is small in comparing with its superscript and the shape of the equation is not interesting. I would to use the idea at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132006/missing-delimiter-inserted), using `\scalebox{}{\(\)}` as follows but it scales the arrow both horizontal and vertical so again the shape of the equation is not interesting. I will be thankful for any other suggestion.

```
$$\left.\begin{array}{rl}
x\notin f(C)\overset{C\cap f^{-1}(D)\subseteq C}{\scalebox{2}{\(\longrightarrow\)}} & x\notin f\big(C\cap f^{-1}(D)\big)\\
& x\in U
\end{array}\right\}\Longrightarrow x\in V$$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you should use the `\xrightarrow` macro and the `rcases` environment of the [mathtools](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package. Using these you can produce

[image]

using the relatively simple code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\[
  x\notin f(C)\xrightarrow{C\cap f^{-1}(D)\subseteq C}
    \begin{rcases}
      & x\notin f\big(C\cap f^{-1}(D)\big)\\
      & x\in U
    \end{rcases}
    \Longrightarrow x\in V
\]

\end{document}
```

Note, in particular, that I have replaced your `$$..$$` with `\[...\]`

Comment: Thank you so much (but $x\in U$ can't be implied from $x\notin f(C)$ plus $C\cap f^{-1}(D)\subseteq C$). And what is the difference of double dollors and the other sign you used? My problem just solved by replacing \overset{}{} by \xrightarrow{}.

Comment: For the difference between double dollar signs and `\[...\]` see [why-is-preferable-to](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to). As regards the mathematics, I just typeset what you had -- as did Peter Gill:)

Comment: Thank you for the link to why `\[...\]` is preferable. But about what I wrote, it was a 2 times 2 array with empty entry at second row-first column, so the result is different than what you both have written.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `tikz` for the *overkill* solution, but gives you a lot of flexibility in terms of the arrow tip, line thickness and color:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\MyArrow}[2][]{%
    \mathbin{%
        \tikz[baseline,remember picture] \node[above, inner sep=1pt, #1, draw=none] (X) at (0,0.5ex) {$\scriptstyle #2$};
        \tikz[baseline,remember picture,overlay] \draw [->, #1] (X.south west) -- (X.south east);
    }%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\Rhs}{%
    \begin{rcases}
      & x\notin f\big(C\cap f^{-1}(D)\big)\\
      & x\in U
    \end{rcases}
    \Longrightarrow x\in V 
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
  x\notin f(C)\MyArrow{C\cap f^{-1}(D)\subseteq C} \Rhs \\
  x\notin f(C)\MyArrow[-latex,draw=red]{C\cap f^{-1}(D)\subseteq C} \Rhs \\
  x\notin f(C)\MyArrow[-stealth,draw=blue,thick]{C\cap f^{-1}(D)\subseteq C} \Rhs \\
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much (but $x\in U$ can't be implied from $x\notin f(C)$ plus $C\cap f^{-1}(D)\subseteq C$). It was too nice to be able to customize shapes of arrows. I like this answer so upvoted it but as the first answer was more simple I chose that one as the answer. I think I will use your suggestions many times in my notes (but not in things like thesis and official ones).